# Eloquent hasMany doesn't load collection

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm relatively new to eloquent, and have problems loading data from a hasMany relation in an app that uses eloquent as the database layer. My (simplified) code is as follows:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Answer extends Model{
    protected $table = 'answer';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        "nerdId",
        "invitationid",
        "eatingno",
        "price",
        "haspaid",
        "attending",
        "noeating",
    ];
    public function topping() {
        return $this->hasMany(AnswerTopping::class, 'answerid');
    }
}

class AnswerTopping extends Model{
    protected $table = 'eating';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'answerid',
        'toppingid',
        'add'
    ];

    public function answer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

The SQL Schema is like below

```
CREATE TABLE `answer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nerdid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invitationid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eatingno` tinytext,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `haspaid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `attending` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `noeating` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2119 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `eating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `toppingid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `add` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I then do the following query:

```php
    $answer = Answer::with('topping')->find(32);
    return $answer->toJson());
```

This results in a json like the following

```json
{"id":32,"nerdid":1,"invitationid":54,"eatingno":"51","price":60,"haspaid":1,"attending":2,"noeating":0,"topping":[]}
```

Raw SQL query shows me that I do have data in the relation, so it should return more in "topping".

**UPDATE**
Checking sql queries in mysql (Setting it up for logging), I see that it actually do the expected queries on the database:

```
select * from `answer` where `answer`.`id` = 32 limit 1;
select * from `eating` where `eating`.`answerid` in (32);
```

Manually executing the SQL are giving me 2 entries in the eating table. But they are not showing up on the upper "Answer" json.

Comment: I don't really see any issues at a glance, so might need to provide more code ( and table structure ) to check

Comment: Added more details to the post...

Comment: btw. the underlying database is from an older incarnation of my project, building on idiorm. But since idiorm is more or less dead, I'm trying to get it to work with eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.. db schema for the "eating" table, had `answerId` (uppercase I), and the relation in hasMany used `answerid` (lowercase i), which apparently confused eloquent..

Now I get the expected json..